# Useful example of a shutdown hook in Java?

Tags: java, shutdown-hook

I'm trying to make sure my Java application takes reasonable steps to be robust, and part of that involves shutting down gracefully. I am reading about [shutdown hooks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/i-signalhandling/?open&l=409,t=grj,p=jsh#9) and I don't actually get how to make use of them in practice.

Is there a practical example out there?

Let's say I had a really simple application like this one below, which writes numbers to a file, 10 to a line, in batches of 100, and I want to make sure a given batch finishes if the program is interrupted. I get how to register a shutdown hook but I have no idea how to integrate that into my application. Any suggestions?

```
package com.example.test.concurrency;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class GracefulShutdownTest1 {
    final private int N;
    final private File f;
    public GracefulShutdownTest1(File f, int N) { this.f=f; this.N = N; }

    public void run()
    {
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(this.f);
            pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
                writeBatch(pw, i);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            pw.close();
        }       
    }

    private void writeBatch(PrintWriter pw, int i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
        {
            int k = i*100+j;
            pw.write(Integer.toString(k));
            if ((j+1)%10 == 0)
                pw.write('\n');
            else
                pw.write(' ');
        }
    }

    static public void main(String[] args)
    {
        if (args.length < 2)
        {
            System.out.println("args = [file] [N] "
                    +"where file = output filename, N=batch count");
        }
        else
        {
            new GracefulShutdownTest1(
                    new File(args[0]), 
                    Integer.parseInt(args[1])
            ).run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722826/when-do-i-need-to-call-this-method-runtime-getruntime-addshutdownhook

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You could do the following:

- Let the shutdown hook set some AtomicBoolean (or volatile boolean) "keepRunning" to false
- (Optionally, `.interrupt` the working threads if they wait for data in some blocking call)
- Wait for the working threads (executing `writeBatch` in your case) to finish, by calling the `Thread.join()` method on the working threads.
- Terminate the program

Some sketchy code:

- Add a `static volatile boolean keepRunning = true;`
- In *run()* you change to

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < N && keepRunning; ++i)
      writeBatch(pw, i);
  ```
- In *main()* you add:

  ```
  final Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
  Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
      public void run() {
          keepRunning = false;
          mainThread.join();
      }
  });
  ```

That's roughly how I do a graceful "reject all clients upon hitting Control-C" in terminal.

---

From [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29):

> When the virtual machine begins its shutdown sequence it will start all registered shutdown hooks in some unspecified order and let them run concurrently. **When all the hooks have finished it will then run all uninvoked finalizers if finalization-on-exit has been enabled. Finally, the virtual machine will halt.**

That is, a shutdown hook keeps the JVM running until the hook has terminated (returned from the *run()*-method.

Comment: Ah -- so if I understand right, the gist of what you're saying is that the shutdown hook has an opportunity to communicate with other currently-running threads, and to hold off the VM shutdown (e.g. by using Thread.join()) until it is satisfied that a quick cleanup has been completed. That's the point I was missing. thanks!

Comment: Yes. You got it. Updated the answer with a few sentences from the docs.

Comment: Sorry in advance,but shouldnt GracefulShutdownTest1 implement Runnable?

Comment: Will this also work a GUI was started in the main thread? I know it's not the best way to do it (use EDT instead), but I'm working on old code.

Comment: Shutdown hooks are unrelated to GUI code. The two should work together just fine.

Comment: @aioobe, Are there any limitations to how long the shutdown hook can run? For example, can it "prevent" the virtual machine from stopping *indefinitely*?

Comment: I don't think there is any limitations. You can prevent the JVM from shutting down by spawning a non daemon thread as well.

Comment: So if this example had been using multiple threads, your `join()` call would be made on the thread doing the work?

Comment: @MartynasJusevičius, the JVM terminates when all non-daemon threads have terminated. If the `mainThread` is a daemon thread, then the `join` guarantees that we wait for it to finish before letting the JVM shut down.