# How to execute a set of commands when exiting a java program?

Tags: java

i want to execute a particular set of commands when the program exits by pressing the cross on the right hand top corner

Comment: Search for "shutdown hook" on stackoverflow. There are several other questions on this topic.

Comment: here's one example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921945/java-useful-example-of-a-shutdown-hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending of what you really want to do, there are few ways to do it:
1) If you want to do it on UI level use WindowListener [[link]](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html)
2) If you want to do it on JVM level, use ShutdownHooks [[link]](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29)