# java, Declaring an method which runs before application close

Tags: java, actionlistener, application-close

I want to make some actions just before my application close.

I see there are action listeners but i have no frame or similar thing. Just an only java file.

How can I able to set some kind of control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
I want to make some actions just before my application close.
```

You're probably looking for a shutdown hook:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(...)
```

Here's a SO question (and great answers) asking for practical uses of shutdown hooks:

[Useful example of a shutdown hook in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921945/useful-example-of-a-shutdown-hook-in-java)