# How to capture event for forcefully quit or unexpected close in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am making a desktop application which has login and logout functionality with server.

I need to logout from the application whenever someone close the window, so I am using these codes

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                    event.consume();
                    closeWindow();
                }
            });
```

where closeWindow() contains logout and other related steps.

Now there is a problem when application closes unexpectedly or when someone forcefully quit/close it from Task Manager (by ending process).

Do JavaFX has any event to capture forcefully quit or unexpected close ? Or if there any method to stop it ?

Answer (score 4):

When your application gets closed via `TaskManager` your only option will be to use the VM's [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html).

There are some examples around, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921945/useful-example-of-a-shutdown-hook-in-java/2922031#2922031).

Comment: I tried using shutdown hook but it dont work when I close application from TaskManager.

Answer (score 3):

There is a method

```
@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    super.stop();
    System.out.println("logout");
}
```

in Application class.

Comment: We think, there is no hope do to smth, when OS kills a process

Comment: If you don't know any theory about operation systems, you may read it, but shortly saying, when OS intends to kill a process, which is done, when you use a taskmanager, a process is stopped, and removed from OM, resources used by process become free. And there is no chance, usually, to run any code before that

Comment: About your client/server application : you should track session on a server, and you shouldn't rely on clients behavior.

Comment: so there is no chance to perform any function before OS kills the process ?
and that will be fine if I track session on server, and surely I will do that.

Comment: Shreyas, there are different reasons, why client can stop responsing: electricity down, network down, blue screen of death on windows.. In common case, you shouldn't rely on client too much. If you have security concerns, you should be especially qualified about client-server communications....

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Gui extends Application {

    static {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                closeWindow();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public final void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        // ...
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a task for that logout procedure, try playing with `setDaemon` method. I solved a similar case by showing a "loading" window and closing that window after the task completes. You can try that too.