# Java - ScheduledExecutorService: Execute task at termination

Tags: java, executorservice, autocloseable

I use the `ScheduledExecutorService` to execute a task at a fixed rate. Here is the contents of my main method:

```
RemoteSync updater = new RemoteSync(config);
try  {
    updater.initialise();
    updater.startService(totalTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`RemoteSync` implements the `AutoCloseable` (and `Runnable`) interface, so I initially used `try-with-resources`, like this:

```
try (RemoteSync updater = new RemoteSync(config)) {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But `updater.startService()` returns immediately after scheduling the task, so the `updater.close()` is called prematurely and the application exits.

Here is the `startService()` method of `RemoteSync`:

```
public void startService(int rate, TimeUnit unit) {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    service =
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this, 1L,
        rate,
        unit);
}
```

Ideally, I would like to have a method like:

```
scheduledExecutorService.executeAtTermination(Runnable task)
```

This will allow me to call `close()` when scheduler has actually stopped, unfortunately I am not aware of such a method.

What I can do, is block the `startService()` method, with something like this:

```
while (!scheduledExecutorService.isTerminated()) {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

but this feels dirty and hackish.

Any suggestion are welcome.

Comment: maybe you can use application shutdown hook. Like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921945/useful-example-of-a-shutdown-hook-in-java) discussion.

Comment: Hmm, I've heard about shutdown hooks. I'll give it a go. Thanks @nukie

Comment: @nukie I ended up using a shutdown hook, if you care to add an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use application shutdown hook. Like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921945/useful-example-of-a-shutdown-hook-in-java) discussion.

You can add code like this in some stage of application initialization:

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    >>> shutdown your service here <<<
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `scheduledExecutorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),` possibly in a separate thread

Comment: Seems like a good option, only problem is there is no set timeout. The application may run for days or even weeks. What I can, is check if the service has been terminated. If not (timeout occurred), I can just call `awaitTermination` again. Thanks for the suggestion though.