# Should I use System.exit(1) when catching an application-stopping Exception?

Tags: java, exception

Say I have the following code:

```
try {
    //Do something with File
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    outputInfo("Error in IO Redirection", true);
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
}
```

My program exits right after this catch location, is a single thread (one main method) program and should not expect to recover from such an exception.

Should I *really* be using `System.exit(1);` ?

Comment: Using an integer 1-127 in system.exit indicates abnormal termination of a program. If you don't want to perform any other operation after catch block you can use it or catch the exception and print with proper error message.

Comment: What alternative are you considering in place of `System.exit(1);`?

Comment: No alternative, I'm just wondering what is required to think about when I'm using `System.exit(1);` and what I should understand might go wrong in using this in all my Exception handling catches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you expect someone else to run your program, and they rely on the process status code to know if your program has succeeded or failed, then you should use `System.exit(1);`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29

> Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine. The argument
>   serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status code
>   indicates abnormal termination.

Comment: What if your program makes use of a finally clause as well. `System.exit(1)` will definitely interfere, does that mean you may have to duplicate finishing up code prior to calling the exit?

Comment: You may either put the `exit` statement out of the `catch` block, or create a [shutdown hook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921945/useful-example-of-a-shutdown-hook-in-java) that will be executed on the JVM termination (after you call `exit`).

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons to use a non zero exit code on failure of an application is that they can be used in batch files. If your application is a console application always use proper exit code. You don't know how it will be used in future.

Comment: I agree. I love future-proofing, exit codes are rarely seen in programs I come across, bizarrely... maybe too much overhead thinking for most.