# calling destructor to call a method before closing JAVA program

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a test with Selenium and JAVA, sometimes when I get an error I use `System.exit(1);` to close my test or in some other situations my test program is forced to finish, but I need to run a function in any case before shutting the program down, so Is there any destructor in Java that if I call my function there it will be called (guaranteed) if any thing forces my program to finish?

Comment: The language facility for this are shutdown hooks, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921945/useful-example-of-a-shutdown-hook-in-java

Comment: When you say "test program is forced to finish", do you mean you kill the process? If you do, then no cleanup code can be run, because that's a hard kill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a `finalizer`, or using a shutdown hook (see [Useful example of a shutdown hook in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921945/useful-example-of-a-shutdown-hook-in-java)), but you really shouldn't be doing that.....

Don't use `System.exit(1)`. Throw an exception and let it to roll back your call stack, allowing each method on the call stack to handle resource cleanup in a `try-finally` block.

You can always catch the exception in your main method and call `System.exit(exitCode)` there, if you need to control the exit code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JUnit to drive your tests, you may be interested in using `@Before` and `@After` to annotate setup and teardown methods. And as Andreas was saying, you should be throwing exceptions instead, then JUnit will deal with calling the teardown methods even in case of errors.