# ShutdownHook is not being called uppon pressing Ctrl+C if programm was started via gradle

Tags: java, gradle, shutdown-hook

I have a program which implements a `Shutdown Hook` in order to ensure everything is closed before the program terminates. If I launch the program from terminal the Shutdown Hook is executed after I press `Ctrl+C`. However if I launch the program with `gradle run` this doesn't happen.

**Questions:**

- Why does this happen?
- Is it possible to ensure that the shutdown hook gets executed when I run the program with gradle?

**Code:**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyShutdownHook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Adding a shutdown hook");
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Shutdown hook was being called.");
        }));

        System.out.println("Enter Exit to terminate the programm.");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isRunning = true;
        while (isRunning) {
            if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String answer = scanner.next();
                if (answer.equals("Exit")) isRunning = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

run {
    standardInput = System.in
}

application {
    mainClass.set("MyShutdownHook")
}
```

Comment: would this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921945/useful-example-of-a-shutdown-hook-in-java

Comment: @sanjeevRm I've also seen this answer. Unfortunately it doesn't really help me. I'm curious about why `gradle run` prevents a `Shutdown-Hook` with `Ctrl+C`.